# which of this transformations are linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[image]

I am having a hard time trying to understand this question and how to start it.
I know that a linear transformation must be closed under addiction and scalar multiplicantion. 
I was wondering if someone can give me a hint of how to start it off.

Comment: *Subspaces* must be closed under [addition] and scalar [multiplication].  Linear transformations are defined as maps which have the following two properties: $$\text{for all $u,v\in V$},\quad T(u+v) = T(u)+T(v) \\ \text{for all $u\in V$ and $k\in \Bbb R$},\quad T(ku) = kT(u)$$

Comment: To show $T_1$ is linear you need to show that $$T_1\left(\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \\ z_2\end{bmatrix}\right) = T_1\left(\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1\end{bmatrix}\right) +T_1\left(\begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \\ z_2\end{bmatrix}\right) \\ \text{and}\qquad T_1\left(k\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1\end{bmatrix}\right) = kT_1\left(\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1\end{bmatrix}\right)$$ using the definition of $T_1$.

Comment: Please don’t include important parts of your question as images. They’re not searchable, they’re inaccessible to people using screen readers, and it shows that you’re unwilling to take your own time to post a question to the standards of this site, but expect others to take their time to answer it.

Comment: @amd I am sorry for the inconvenience. I have just started learning Latex so it will take a while till I learn how to type "fancy" like in the picture. If you prefere I can write it like this "Suppose u1, u2, u3, is a basis for R^3. For each v = x⃗u1 + y⃗u2 + z⃗u3 in R^3 let
T1(⃗v)=[x z y]^T  T2(⃗v)=[y y z]^T    T3(⃗v)=[x+y y z]^T   T4(⃗v)=[y−x y z]^T T5(⃗v)=[0 x+z 0^]T
Which of these transformations are linear?"

Comment: It would be a start. Thanks. You’ll pick up MathJax pretty quickly, I think.